# Why are there several "expressions" in the English language related to the third month of the year?

Tags: expressions

You can find some examples of the phenomenon in question below:

1. Ides of **March**
2. **March** hare, mad as a **March** hare
3. **March** madness
4. Winds of **March**, **March** winds (I recall that the [MAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_%28magazine%29) staff even produced a special **March** winds issue many decades ago).

Can you name another month of the year which is as "popular" in the English language as **March**? If not, do you have any clue as to why it is that there several "expressions" in English which allude to that month?

Thanks in advance for you insightful replies.

Comment: In one word, _Spring._ In the Northern Hemisphere, where English evolved, March was the month when life outside the house began to happen again. And life for every other species began to be very vigorous, which did not escape people's attention.

Comment: It might be... By the way, I read once that March was the first month of the Roman(?) year.

Comment: Yes, that's why September, October, November, and December were the seventh, eighth, ninth, and tenth months. January and February were the eleventh and twelfth.

Comment: You are marching too much into March. March on elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not convinced there are an unusually high number of expressions. If there are, you'll have to come up with more and better examples. Four is not a huge number, and two of these are readily explained:

- "Ides of March" is simply alludes to the date of the assassination of Julius Caesar, popularized by Shakespeare.
- "March Madness" is simply an alliterative term derived from the timing of a particular sporting event (not unlike "Mr. October" for a baseball player who excels during the playoffs, or the recently-popularized expression, "You can't script October.").

I suppose the fact that March is a monosyllabic month may make it more readily apt to be incorporated into short expressions, much like May is:

> April showers bring May flowers
>   *It's just a spring clean for the May queen*
>   The Maypole dance on May day
>   *murmur'd that their May was passing*

Comment: You are right... Four examples is not a huge number of them or, in other words, one swallow doesn't a summer make. I've rephrased my question accordingly.